# How to read the last line of a text file into a variable using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, git-bash

I want to read a text file called history.txt that contains multiple lines and store the content of the last line into a variable called "tag".

Thanks

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`tag=$( tail -n 1 history.txt )`

Answer (score -5):

```
cat FileName | while read oneline
do
echo "a oneline: $line"
done
```

Comment: omg... this is not only in bad style ([UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html), `read` without the `-r`, no indentation), but it doesn't answers the question. The OP want store the last line into the variable `tag`...

Comment: thanks for answering

Comment: because. 1.) the answer is already here 2.) the question isn't good for the StackOverflow. Looks like you also need read thru:   [help] and [tour].