# How to only read the last line from a text file

Tags: bash, text, awk, grep, tac

I am working on a tool project. I need to grab the last line from a file & assign into a variable. This is what I have tried:

```
line=$(head -n $NF input_file)
echo $line
```

Maybe  I could read the file in reverse then use

```
line=$(head -n $1 input_file)
echo $line
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Point to be noted here is `$NF` is `awk`'s terminology so not sure why you have mentioned in shell command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `tail` ;)

```
line=$(tail -n 1 input_file)
echo $line
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42987505/499581

Answer (score 2):

Combination of `tac` and `awk` here. Benefit in this approach could be we need  NOT to read complete Input_file in it.

```
tac Input_file | awk '{print;exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` or `awk` :

```
sed -n '$p' file
sed '$!d' file
awk 'END{print}' file
```

However, `tail` is still the right tool to do the job.